# PHP session_id( ) null

Tags: php, sessionid

I am having some difficulty with sessions.

On my local MAMP test server, if I do:

session_start( );
echo session_id( );

I get a nice looking session id.

If However, I the same thing on my web server, all I can get back from session_id is 'null'.  Testing the return from session_start( ) and using sessions everything is working, but session_id( ) $SID and $PHPSESSID are all null.

Is this hidden on purpose for added security?  I want to be able to allow flash to make changes to a shopping cart through PHP calls and have the cart (which is stored in the session) reflected using the browser.

Comment: What happens if you do session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: Valid session variable:

array(1) { ["product"]=>  &array(1) { [0]=>  string(21) "frame-13-1-260-237-18" } } 

Then session_id( ) still reports null...

Comment: null? Strange as session_id should only return the id or an empty string.

Comment: If I " echo 'Session is: ' . session_id( ); "  I get "Session is: null".

Comment: If I var_dump( session_id( ) ) I get: string(4) "null"...

So it is actually a string of "null".  Not NULL

Comment: Multiple browsers / multiple computers all show different $_SESSIONS but all return a string of "null" from session_id( ).  Must be a new security issue / setting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure the return value of session_start() is TRUE.

Make sure you are calling session_start() before your script outputs anything to the browser.

Check that apache has write access to the session path. Mine is /tmp

Comment: session_start( ) TRUE.

Very beginning of file is <?  session_start( ); ...

Mine is /tmp and sessions are indeed working.  (Cart is functional, ...)  and the script works on MAMP.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (`session_id()` returned `""`, I hope, this is related to your question). I closed all corresponding tabs and deleted all relevant cookies, then re-opened the site and now `session_id()` returns a beautiful hash value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an edge case, but for me, I solved it by testing the return value of `session_start()` which showed it to be false.

The issue turned out to be the encoding of the actual file. It was emitting something invisible before the session started, even though it looked like nothing was there.

I solved it by copying the relevant files into a plain text editor (I used https://www.editpad.org/), deleting the source file on, recreating the empty file, pasting that code I had run through editpad, and reuploading.

After that everything started populating normally.

Comment: Another good example of plain text editor is https://pasteepad.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Windows and for me it was caused by the *ini* setting *session.save_path* having an invalid path defined.